# Pandas to calculate pct_change on specified freq option

Tags: python, pandas, database

I would like to calculate 1 year, 2, years, 3 years growth rate of weekly/daily DataFrame :

```
start = '20100101'
end = '20201117'

df_ts = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.bdate_range(start=start, end=end, freq='D'))
df_ts['valeur1'] = range(1, df_ts.shape[0]+1)

df_ts['gr'] = 100*df_ts.pct_change(periods=1, freq='Y)
df_ts
```

I thought `pct_change(periods=n, freq='Y')` was the good way to do it but I get an error result with this simple date.

I need to emphasise that in my data I have weekly/daily data and I operate others operation so I need to put this inside `apply(lambda x: x.pct_change(periods=n, freq='Y')`.

Any suggestions to do it simply ?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a new dataframe to a column because you did `.pct_change` on the dataframe not the column. Try this:

```
df_ts['gr'] = df_ts['valeur1'].pct_change(periods=1, freq='Y')
```

Comment: It produces the calendar performance but I would like the rolling 1 year (2 yrs...) growth rates

Comment: I've got it : ```freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1)```  instead of ```freq='Y'```